# How to set focus/onHover button color programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I use this code for generate some button :

```
public void addButton(int channel, int start, int length, String texte)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = newRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int top = MARGE_SUPERIEUR + HAUTEUR_LIGNE * channel;
    int left = MARGE_GAUCHE + PIXELMINUTE * start;


    lprams.setMargins(left,top,0,0);

    Button Button = new Button(this.context);
    Button.setText(texte);
    Button.setMaxHeight(10);
    Button.setTextSize(10);
    Button.setLayoutParams(lprams);
    Button.setWidth(length*PIXELMINUTE);

    rLayout.addView(Button);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("Clicked", "Clicked" + channel + start);
        }
    });

}
```

It works fine, but I want to change the color when I focus/hover one these button.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the onFocusChangeListener() to listen to onFocus()

```
btn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (hasFocus) {
            //Toast line...
        }
    }

});
```

For changing the button color :

btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: Ok, and to reverse, when it's Unfocused ?

Comment: @Arnaud        Yes. If this solved your problem, please mark it as an answer so that it can help others also